# Is it possible to install and work on CUDA Toolkit on ElementaryOS or Deepin?

Tags: linux, nvidia, elementary-os, deepin

And as far as I know that they're based on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I'm I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

elementary OS is based on ubuntu, it should work without problems